# TKinter checkbox behaves different in different contexsts

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I following code I create a window with just a checkbox and a button. When I get value of the checkbox by executing just the checkbox window, everything goes fine. When I construct that window from another window, checkbox behaves unexpectedly. Feel free to run following code. Result I get is:

```
1
0
```

I just don't get it why the second result is 0 and not 1. Any ideas?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Checkbutton

class SecondaryWindow:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.decimal_comma = tk.IntVar()

        Checkbutton(window, variable = self.decimal_comma).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        Button(window, text = "Check the checkbox and click me", command = self.ok_pressed).grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    def ok_pressed(self, event = None):
        print(self.decimal_comma.get())
        self.window.destroy()

class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        Button(self, text = "Click me", command = self.popup).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def popup(self, event = None):
        loader = SecondaryWindow(Tk())
        loader.window.wait_window()
        self.destroy()

def main1():
    MainWindow().mainloop()

def main2():
    top = Tk()

    loader = SecondaryWindow(top)
    loader.window.wait_window()

    top.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main2()
    main1()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be only one `Tk` window at a time - use `Toplevel` to create another  window

```
loader = SecondaryWindow(Toplevel())
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full code - it works for me.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Checkbutton, Toplevel

class SecondaryWindow:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.decimal_comma = tk.IntVar()

        Checkbutton(window, variable = self.decimal_comma).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        Button(window, text = "Check the checkbox and click me", command = self.ok_pressed).grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    def ok_pressed(self, event = None):
        print(self.decimal_comma.get())
        self.window.destroy()

class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        Button(self, text = "Click me", command = self.popup).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def popup(self, event = None):
        loader = SecondaryWindow(Toplevel())
        loader.window.wait_window()
        self.destroy()

def main1():
    MainWindow().mainloop()

def main2():
    top = Tk()

    loader = SecondaryWindow(top)
    loader.window.wait_window()

    top.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main2()
    main1()
```

Comment: Did the replacement, I still get the same problem.

Comment: I add full code to answer - it works for me - linux mint/python 3.4.3

Comment: Your answer suggests using `Toplevel`, yet your example code creates more than once instance of `Tk`. That seems incongruent.

Comment: Maybe I should say "one mainloop can work with one Tk window". There are two mainloops in code so every mainloop has own Tk.

Comment: Hm. I obviously previously messed something up real hard because now when I modify my code as you said - everything works as expected. Interesting. Anyway, you solved the problem, thank you, here is your green tick :-) Thanks!